# iPhone 4, only emergency calls

Tags: iphone, sim, unlock

I bought new Neverlock (sim free) iPhone 4 with 4.3.5 firmware. Then I would like to return it to factory settings and click "Restore" in iTunes. But after restoring i received unlocking device with "only emergency calls" message. What can i do now?

Answer (score 1):

You bought one? From where? I ask because once you've restored in iTunes if it's a properly unlocked device it'll let you straight back in, emergency calls only means it's not been registered against a network, or unlocked.

Comment: False alarm. You were right, I put the sim card and after reconnecting to iTunes it is unlocked.